# How to migrate the Conditional Running Total Field in Crystal Report to MS SQL Server Reporting Service

Tags: crystal-reports, business-intelligence, reporting-services

For example, there is a DB view named as View_NegAsset with fields:

1. Equity_Percent
2. L_PD_MTH
3. HKD_BAL

Inside the Crystal Report [Edit Running Total Field], we have:
Field to summarize: HKD_BAL
Type of summary: sum
Use a formula: {View_NegAsset.Equity_Percent} <= 60 and {View_NegAsset.L_PD_MTH} = 1

Please kindly advise what will be the corresponding SSRS expression?

Thank you very much.

BRs,
William

Comment: What's the reset on this, and where is it printed? Is this a true running total, or are you using Crystal's running total functionality to derive a conditional sum? Also, what does BRs mean?

Comment: Hi Mark, I'm new to Crystal report. This is one parameter showed in the "Running Total Fields". As my understanding, I believe it is about to derive a conditional sum.  BRs means Best Regards.

Comment: Hi William, if you edit your running total field in Crystal you should see a set of options down the right hand side under the field name: Field to summarize, Type of summary, Evaluate and Reset. I think you have already included the details of the first three options in your question, but not the fourth - which can be set to Never, On change of field, On change of group or a formula. Please can you include which of these is selected? (If it is reset on change of the same group where it is printed, then I think you are right - it is not a true running total, but a conditional sum.)

Comment: Hi Mark, It uses OnChangeOfGroup. However, I've done a lot of try-and-errors, and now, at least, from the perspective of the result, I can duplicate the report computation from the Crystal to SSRS for this case. Such migration work is really hard and tired~